# given A and B are mxn and nxm matrices. What can we say about their eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices, transpose

I know that the sum of the eigenvalues will be the same. But can we say something about them individually? 
When A is transpose(B) I'm getting something interesting

A = (1  2  0)
    (0 -1  2)

B =  (1  0)
     (2 -1)
     (0  2)

AB has 7,3 as eigenvalues
BA has 3,7,0 as eigenvalues

Comment: Do you mean for $AB$ and $BA$ to be $m\times m$ and $n\times n$? If so, please edit the title accordingly. You know that if $AB$ is $m\times n$ with $m\ne n$ then it makes no sense to talk about eigenvalues, right?

Comment: sorry I meant A is mxn and B is nxm

Comment: Then please edit the question so it says what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Eigenvalues aren't defined for rectangular matrices, but the singular values are closely related: The right and left singular values for rectangular matrix $M$ are the eigenvalues of $M'M$ and $MM'.$

Source: [Eigenvalues of a rectangular matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207991/eigenvalues-of-a-rectangular-matrix)